# setting proper path based on servlet request

Tags: jsp, servlets, path

I have an include that I am using in a jsp. Works great except sometimes I am in a different directory and my logo doesn’t render. 
My code, stored in alternate directories, are patterned. See example of naming convention. Looking for a way to *wildcard*.

pathOneYear/programNo/home.mtc

How can I ensure that my img src is pointing to the correct directory level?

```
enter code here
   <%if (request.getServletPath().contains("/myPath/index.mtc")){%>
        <img src="../images/my_logo.gif" width="99" height="23" alt="blah blah" class="logo"  />
    <%}else{%>}
        <img src="images/my_logo.gif" width="99" height="23" alt=" blah blah " class="logo"  />
     <%}%>
```

Maybe something like this...

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding a way to wildcard, i suggest you place the logo image in the application's WEB-INF directory and serve it as static content like:

```
<img src="<YOUR_URL>/my_logo.gif"....
```

Comment: thank you lonchu. I'll give that a whirl. Might have to bend our file standards for this one. ;^)